# "opencv_contrib is required but was not found" error while making cmake

Tags: cmake, opencv3.1

I need to run the code on this repository: https://github.com/KirillLykov/oni2avi

I have OpenCV 3.1.0 installed.

When I build the code with cmake, I get the following error:

> "opencv_contrib is required but was not found"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For those who will have problems with this code on github and read this post - try opening an issue on the project page, may be I will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting extra modules for OpenCV [from contrib repository](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib), change

```
find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS core highgui video imgproc contrib REQUIRED)
```

to

```
find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS core highgui video imgproc rgbd REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 1):

Download opencv_contrib from github and in cmake set variable OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH to FullPathOPENCVCONTRIB/modules. rebuild opencv

If it does not work you can try to delete contrib dependancy in [CMakelists.txt](https://github.com/KirillLykov/oni2avi/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) :

find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS core highgui video imgproc ***contrib*** REQUIRED)